# Gradle - two plugins have the same root block name, which resolve conflict

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I'm trying to use 2 different plugins that have the same root block name, what's causing conflict and error in the build process.

The 2 plugins are defined in the **build.gradle** :

```
plugins {
  id 'java'
  id 'application'
  id 'com.benjaminsproule.swagger' version '1.0.8'
  id 'org.detoeuf.swagger-codegen' version '1.7.4'
}
apply plugin: 'org.detoeuf.swagger-codegen'

version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
mainClassName = 'ServiceMain'

swagger {
    apiSource {
        springmvc = true
        locations = ['com.google.charger']
        schemes = ['https']
        info {
            title = 'Swagger Gradle Plugin Sample'
            version = 'v1'
        }
        swaggerDirectory = 'swagger'
        swaggerFileName = 'charger-service-api-swagger'
        attachSwaggerArtifact = true
    }
}

swagger {
    inputSpec = "${project.projectDir}/swagger/charger-service-api-swagger.json"
    outputDir = file("${project.projectDir}/../charger-server-api-client/")
    lang = 'java'

    additionalProperties = [
            'invokerPackage'         : 'com.google.ev.charger.server',
            'modelPackage'           : 'com.google.ev.charger.server.model',
            'apiPackage'             : 'com.google.ev.charger.server.api',
            'dateLibrary'            : 'joda',
            'groupId'                : 'com.google.ev',
            'artifactId'             : 'charger.server',
            'artifactVersion'        : '1.0.0',
            'hideGenerationTimestamp': 'true'
    ]
}

sourceSets {
    swagger {
        java {
            srcDir file("${project.buildDir.path}/swagger/src/main/java")
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see both plugins starts with the same block name (swagger),
Is there any way to specify the plugin for each configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using code to resolve this issue,
I am using a property called **"CreateSwagger"** that I'm passing (either from CLI or from gradle.properties file) to separate the 2 scenarios.

The issue I had is that the ***plugins {}*** block is not allowed inside the if that evaluates the condition so I needed to use the "old" legacy plugin ***" apply plugin:"***

This is how my **build.gradle** ended up looking:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.benjaminsproule:swagger-gradle-plugin:1.0.8"
        classpath "gradle.plugin.org.detoeuf:swagger-codegen-plugin:1.7.4"
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'maven'
}

if(project.properties.containsKey('CreateSwagger')){
    apply plugin: "com.benjaminsproule.swagger"
} else {
    apply plugin: 'org.detoeuf.swagger-codegen'
}

version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
mainClassName = 'EVChargerRestServiceMain'

if(project.properties.containsKey('CreateSwagger')){
    swagger {
        apiSource {
            springmvc = true
            locations = ['com.google.charger']
            schemes = ['https']
            info {
                title = 'Swagger Gradle Plugin Sample'
                version = 'v1'
            }
            swaggerDirectory = 'swagger'
            swaggerFileName = 'charger-service-api-swagger'
            attachSwaggerArtifact = true
        }
    }
}
else {
    swagger {
        inputSpec = "${project.projectDir}/swagger/charger-service-api-swagger.json"
        outputDir = file("${project.projectDir}/../charger-server-api-client/")
        lang = 'java'

        additionalProperties = [
                'invokerPackage'         : 'com.google.ev.charger.server',
                'modelPackage'           : 'com.google.ev.charger.server.model',
                'apiPackage'             : 'com.google.ev.charger.server.api',
                'dateLibrary'            : 'joda',
                'groupId'                : 'com.google.ev',
                'artifactId'             : 'charger.server',
                'artifactVersion'        : '1.0.0',
                'hideGenerationTimestamp': 'true'
        ]
    }
}
```